# Spree Commerce: Multiple colors with its own SKU

Tags: ruby-on-rails, e-commerce, spree

This is example of what I need:

```
http://www.pruneshop.com/billeteras/fichero-de-cuero-p100602vg.html
http://demo.commerceguys.com/dc/catalog/coffee-holders/mug
```

What I need: In each post, it has multiple colors represented by the image of each color, each color has its own SKU.

In lots of Spree Commerce example, I cannot find any example that doing what I need

This example built on Spree Commerce. It looks similar to what I need:

```
http://onlinestore.thurley.com.au/products/velvet-maxi-dress-velvet-cinder
```

But even it looks similar, the "Color" is actually a link to other post. when clicking "black" from dropdown, it redirected to `http://onlinestore.thurley.com.au/products/velvet-maxi-dress-velvet-black`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

apasajja,

This should be handled out of the box with OptionValues and Variants. Set up your optionType of "Color", your OptionValues for each color, and a variant for any of the relevant colors. Each Variant holds a SKU value.